# MID & FIND Logical in Excel with a space

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have some data that looks like the following;

**Paul Smith Motorcycles/ Inv#1250/ NQX**

I am trying to retrieve the "Inv#1250" out of the data.
I can do this by using the following query;

=MID(P154,FIND("INV",P154)+0,8)

This returns me the data.

**However** some lines have a space in between the INV like so...

Peter Pane/ Inv# 1264
Joe Bloe/ Inv# 1265
Mary Jane/ Inv# 1266

How do I write an expression/query that will search for INV#1250 OR INV# 1265 when there is sometimes a space inbetween the data I want to find?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could test if there is a space and then change the number of chars the MID returns:

`=MID(B4,FIND("Inv",B4)+0,IF(ISERROR(FIND("Inv# ",B4)),8,9))`

You could then extend with SUBSTITUTE to get consistency by removing the space:

`=SUBSTITUTE(MID(B3,FIND("Inv",B3)+0,IF(ISERROR(FIND("Inv# ",B3)),8,9))," ","")`

Answer (score 0):

Another way would be to simply use SUBSTITUTE to remove spaces first, i.e.

`=MID(SUBSTITUTE(P154," ",""),SEARCH("INV#",SUBSTITUTE(P154," ","")),8)`